# Authorize my Apps to use my web services

Tags: php, javascript, api, rest, oauth

I have been trying to get my mind around this process for weeks now with no luck, every time I get something I have more questions. Anyways here is my question and yes I have read all other similar questions and what nots all over the place. Sorry if I sound frustrated but I am. ;)

I have build a handful of restful web services with PHP, currently everyone can access them if they know the url.

I need a way of only authorizing my apps which are a website, iOS app, and android app to be able to use the services. Lets focus on the website, I am using ajax calls to get data from the services.

There is no user authentication, its only apps accessing the services.

How can I make it so that only my apps can access the services?

Comment: Are the users of your apps authenticating as themselves (User to Machine) so you need to check permissions for the user credentials. Or do you just want to ensure it's one of your apps that are connecting (Machine to Machine) and users don't need to login?

Comment: (Machine to Machine) and users don't need to login

Answer (score 0):

This should be rather obvious. Set a password parameter that is passed to the app. Only your apps know the password and can pass it. Roughly this is how app authentication works. So your api can now match the password against its own copy and see if they match. If they don't, deny the service

Comment: But in javascript the password would be exposed to everyone, how is that protecting anything?

Comment: Is there any sort of authentication on the site, or is it public? You can have the "password" sent after the user authenticates, and then destroy it later (after some time, or at logout), with a new one sent upon subsequent authentication. You'd just have to keep a table of valid tokens.

Comment: @Ryuutatsuo Authenticate it with sessions then. Use a nonce to authenticate the application (if it rests on your server). a nonce is a generated token that is stored in session. and passed to the frontend. The frotend uses this token to authorize its applications. This can be changed periodically. IF the app doesn't rest on your server, it has now ay of knowing what the nonce at any given time should be